# How to show results for schemes when the affine case is easy?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For example, I have to show every scheme admits a morphism $X\to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$

or that $\operatorname{Hom}_S(T,\mathbb{A}_S^1)\cong \mathcal{O}_T(T)$ for every $S$-scheme T, where $S$ is affine

If I assume that $X$ and $T$ are spec of ring that's easy. How shall I prove those for schemes? I don't know how to glue together these results

Answer (score 1):

Recall that there is a natural isomorphism $$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sch}}(X, \operatorname{Spec}{A}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Ring}}(A, \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)).$$ Gluing cannot be completely avoided, as the proof of this result requires some work via gluing. You can find it in every introduction on scheme theory.

Comment: So this is correct for schemes X, not just for affine one? I believe it true, so I should consult it in literature

Comment: @RichardChen Yes, one only needs that the codomain is an affine scheme.